# Homeomorphisms in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Consider $(0,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ open in the upper-right quarter plane but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (I mean such that if $(x,y)\in U$ then $x,y\ge0$) which is homeomorphic to an open half-ball in $\mathbb{H}^2$? I guess the answer is negative, but i'm not sure. If so, how can I prove it?

$\mathbb{H}^2=${$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y\ge0$}

open half-ball: {$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:(x-x_0)^2+y^2<r^2$ and $y\ge0$}, for some $r>0,x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

upper-right quarter plane: {$(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:y\ge0$ and $x\ge0$}

Comment: Please define your terms precisely: "upper-right half plane," "open half-ball," "$\mathbb H^2$."

Comment: @JackLee I edited :)

Comment: hint: try mapping $\{(x,y): x\geq 0, y\geq >0, x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ to the open half ball of radius 1 centred at the origin.

Comment: There is an upper right quarter plane, aka quadrant, but upper right half plane ... no.